# How do i find/count number of variable in string using Python

Tags: python-3.x

Here is example of string

Hi {{1}},

The status of your leave application has changed,
Leaves: {{2}}
Status: {{3}}

See you soon back at office by Management.

Expected Result:
Variables Count = 3

i tried python count() using if/else, but i'm looking for sustainable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re

PATTERN = re.compile(r'\{\{\d+\}\}', re.DOTALL)

def count_vars(text: str) -> int:
    return sum(1 for _ in PATTERN.finditer(text))
```

`PATTERN` defines the regular expression. The regular expression matches all strings that contain at least one digit (`\d+`) within a pair of curly brackets (`\{\{\}\}`). Curly brackets are special characters in regular expressions, so we must add `\`. `re.DOTALL` makes sure that we don't skip over new lines (`\n`). The `finditer` method iterates over all matches in the text and we simply count them.

Comment: thanks a lot your solution works as intended and your explanation is much helpful for me understand whats happening, you have saved day.